# What are the benefits of the cake approach under old fashioned trait extending?

Tags: scala, cake-pattern

I'm trying to find out what is the difference between mixing traits via Cake pattern and mixing them via old fashioned extending. Here are my two examples:

*Via extending*

```
trait X {
  def foo()
}

trait Y extends X {
  def bar()
}

class Z extends Y {
  def foo() = ()
  def bar() = ()
}
```

*And via Cake*

```
trait N {
  def foo()
}

trait M {
  this: N =>
  def bar()
}

class U extends M with N {
  def bar() = ()
  def foo() = ()
}
```

What are the benefits of the cake approach? They are both the same for me. Maybe I'm wrong, but I can't see any significant difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I want to enrich the functionalities of `X`, the first approach:

```
// I am X
// I give you everything X provides
trait Y extends X {
  def bar()
}
```

If I want to use functionality of `N`, I would use the second approach:

```
// I am an extension of N
// I require you to be N
trait M { this: N =>
  def bar()
}
```

The main benefit of "the cake approach" over the "old fashion" is not setting the hierarchy constraint *upfront* and avoiding (eventually) the diamond problem by using the "trait linearization".

The traits forming the `class U` implemented in your example get resolved from right to left. Having a sane Method Resolution Order (MRO) gives us the freedom of mixing any trait in a "stackable fashion".